# Is there an equivalent for defparameter on emacs-lisp?

Tags: elisp, common-lisp

I know we have `defvar` and `setq`. `defvar` has a special meaning on defining global variables because the assignment only happens once. So I was thinking about use `setq` to get the desired behavior of `defparameter` from Common Lisp. However when I use `setq` without `defvar` (as replacement) I got a warning: `reference to free-variable`.

I saw on the table of [hyperpolyglot lisp global-var section](http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp#global-var) which relates `defparameter` with `setq` and `set`, so seems this is common. But I'm still wondering about the warnings...

There is another alternative to declare global variables as `defparameter` does? (declare and can change calling again)

Comment: It's not nearly as big of a problem in practice that `defvar` doesn't reset the variable when loading lisp code, you can `C-M-x` on the form to reset it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Emacs Lisp, `defconst` doesn't actually enforce constness, and therefore works pretty much like Common Lisp's `defparameter`:

- it unconditionally sets the variable;
- it marks it as special;
- it avoids any warnings due to setting unbound variables.

Comment: Great to know!!! You could describe the difference between the usage of `setq-default` compared to `defconst`?

Comment: If a variable is buffer-local, `setq-default` sets the default value, while `setq` and `defconst` set the local value.  So they're completely different.  Don't use `setq-default` unless you understand what it does.

Answer (score 7):

Not as far as I can tell, no.

I've always questioned the usefulness of having both defvar and defparameter in Common Lisp.  If you don't mind, leave a comment explaining why having both forms is useful - I'm honestly interested to know.  I know what they do, I just don't know why the difference is important enough for both forms to be in the standard.

Anyway, here's a macro that works for me:

```
(defmacro defparameter (var value &optional docstring)
  `(if (boundp ',var)
       (setq ,var ,value)
     (defvar ,var ,value ,docstring)))
```

That's my first `defmacro`, so feel free to offer improvements.  I'm normally a scheme guy.

Comment: Where do I put my documentation ?

Comment: Right after the parameter list, like a regular Emacs function.  Try doing `M-x find-function` and finding the source for something like `when` or `dolist` for examples.

Comment: I was thinking... `setq-default` would not do exactly what I want? At least when I tested worked as I expected without warnings.

Comment: About usefulness of both forms on Common Lisp, this is something I have my doubts too. `defvar` can avoid the problem of reload file or calling again of some function. Let say we want declare (defvar counter 0) inside of a function as similar of static of C, but is bad calling again as it because will erase our counter. `defparameter`, in another hand, ensure that the value is setted with dynamic-binding and resetted (if was declared previously).  Actually, I always wondered why have so much ways to assign variables (setq, setf, setv, set, defvar, defparameter) in CL... but too late to ask.

Comment: I like in general use `defparameter` instead `defvar` to declare global variables in CL. This avoid problems on development with emacs and the need to manually reset variables — is painful sometimes. Because if you are changing the code a lot, and you have really much code, the better way is just restart the REPL. But using defparameter you just re-eval the buffer. BTW, at least reading the code of community, defparameter is a common practice. I only see defvar used when that line of code have the intention to be executed again and we don't want to change the value when this happens in anyway.

Comment: I think politza was suggesting to change your code to `(defmacro defparameter (var value documentation) ...)`

Comment: Probably yes, @npostavs. It's worth to remember that defparameter can have the optional documentation string.  In that case `(defmacro defparameter (var value &optional doc) ...)` will do the job.

Comment: Of course since you attach the documentation string to `defvar` inside of the macro. From SBCL: DEFPARAMETER names a macro:
  Lambda-list: (VAR VAL &OPTIONAL (DOC))

Answer (score 1):

This version of defparameter in elisp tries to be a bit tighter - requiring the name to be a non-nil symbol, the documentation if present to be a string, and ensuring that the initial-value form is not evaluated more than once (in case it has side-effects).

```
(defmacro defparameter (name &optional initial-value documentation)
  "Like `cl-defvar', but unconditionally sets the named variable to the evaluation of the `initial-value' form."
  (assert (and name (symbolp name)) t "Name must be a non-nil symbol")
  (assert (or (not documentation) (stringp documentation)) t "Documentation if passed must be a string")
  (let ((value-sym (cl-gensym "value")))
    `(let ((,value-sym ,initial-value))
       (cond
         ((boundp ',name)
          (setq ,name ,value-sym)
          ,@(and documentation `((put ',name 'variable-documentation ,documentation)))
          ',name)
         (t
          (defvar ,name ,value-sym ,@(and documentation `(,documentation))))))))
```