# Association in Elisp not found

Tags: association-lists

I have a simple alist in elisp like this:

```
(defvar *oneliners*
  '((js . "//")
    (python . "#")
    ))
```

I am a bit surprised that searching for the python key gives me `nil`. I am calling it from within the function:

```
(defun one (lang)
  (cdr (assoc lang *oneliners*)))

(one 'js) ;; -> "//"
```

But:

```
(one 'python) ;; -> nil
```

What am i missing about elisp's alists?

Comment: Note that the initial value is used **only if the current value is void**. That is, if you change the value in the defvar, then evaluate the defvar again, the value is not updated.  You can use setq to change the value (or use defconst instead of defvar).

Comment: If this turns out to be your problem, I'll post an answer detailing that.

Comment: Yes that was the problem, what is the elisp counterpart of CL defparameter?

Comment: I dont know CL so I can't say.

Comment: @amirt See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/35294/is-there-an-equivalent-for-defparameter-on-emacs-lisp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that may be unexpected with `defvar` is that (from its docstring):

> The optional argument INITVALUE is evaluated, and used to set SYMBOL,
>   only if SYMBOL’s value is void.

That is, if you change the initvalue in the defvar and evaluate it again (eg with `eval-last-sexp`, the new initvalue is not taken into account.  However, you can use the command `eval-defun` (bound to `C-M-x` in `elisp-mode`)

> If the current defun is actually a call to ‘defvar’ or ‘defcustom’,
>   evaluating it this way resets the variable using its initial value
>   expression (using the defcustom’s :set function if there is one), even
>   if the variable already has some other value.

Note that `defconst` does not have this behavior (from its docstring):

> The ‘defconst’ form always sets the value of SYMBOL to the result of
>   evalling INITVALUE.